# Limit point question $a=]0,1[$ and $b=]1,2[$ then $a' \cap b'= \varnothing$

Tags: limits

I don't know how to aprroach this:
Is about limit point:

I don't know if is true or false:

If $a=]0,1[$ and $b=]1,2[$ then $a' \cap b'= \varnothing$

Comment: For those less familiar with these notations, does $]0,1[$ mean the open interval?

Comment: Does $a'$ denote the closure of $a$? If so, then $1\in a'$ and $1\in b'$.

Comment: $1$ is a limit point (and the only common one) for both sets